# CSS not loading in EJS in subdirectory

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, ejs

This is my folder structure (views is in root dir):

> views/contractor/auth/login.ejs

When I go to that file, the CSS doesn't exist. It is not connecting to the CSS which is in (public is in root dir):

> public/assets/css/styles.css

This is my *app.js* (in root dir):

```
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public/css"));
app.use("/public/css/images", express.static("./public/css/images"));
```

However, if I go to another file called *home.ejs* which is in the views root directory, the CSS works.

I believe it has something to do with the subdirectory structure not being defined by `app.use` in my *app.js* file. Could someone please explain to me why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in your HTML page, you are using the absolute link to the css which refers to the server link but the page when it's executing, it calls css from the browser.

I don't have the HTML code to confirm that so thing you can to do is: type F12 when you open the page and try to search in loaded files in the html page, if your css is successfully loaded, it should to appear in hierarchy of file list, use the link to the css from the root folder and put it in the import of css file. Let me know if it works! I hop so.

Comment: yeah you're spot on, thank you